# Spring4 / Java 8 / Weblogic 12 - WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule recursive calls causing StackOverFlowError

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, workmanagertaskexecutor

We have migrated our enterprise software from Java 7 to Java 8, and along with it updated Spring to version 4.3.4. Since then the deployment is failing as one of the beans cannot be initialized due to a StackOverflowError:

```
Caused By: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule(WorkManagerTaskExecutor.java:204)
```

As you can see, the method schedule() is getting called recursively, causing the stack overflow. 
The application is deployed on Weblogic version 12.1.3; here is the code snippet from WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule():

```
return this.workManager.schedule(work);
```

So this should delegate the scheduling call to the target WorkManager object. However, based on our debugging analysis the private member *workManager* inside *WorkManagerTaskExecutor* has been initialized with an instance of type *WorkManagerTaskExecutor*, i.e. when *this.workManager.schedule(work);* is executed, it is calling *WorkManagerTaskExecutor.schedule()*, leading to the recursive call.

The target WorkManager for Weblogic is set-up in the deployment descriptors as follows:
...

```
<resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>wm/MyWorkManager</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
            <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
        </resource-ref>
```

...

```
<work-manager>
    <name>wm/ODSCacheWorkManager</name>
    <max-threads-constraint>
        <name>MaxThreads</name>
        <count>1</count>
    </max-threads-constraint>
    <ignore-stuck-threads>true</ignore-stuck-threads>
</work-manager>
```

...

And inside Spring application context:

```
<bean autowire="byType" id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
            <property name="workManagerName" value="java:comp/env/wm/MyWorkManager"/>
            <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
        </bean>
```

We are seriously running out of ideas why *workManager* inside *WorkManagerTaskExecutor* is initialized with an instace of *WorkManagerTaskExecutor* again, leading to the recursion. Can the community help?